# How to change the colour of the 'Cancel' button on the UISearchBar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have added a `UISearchBar` to the top of my `PFQueryTableViewController`. I have changed the colour of the searchBar to be the colour of my app, but in doing this, it seems to have also changed the colour of the 'Cancel' button to the right of it to the same colour. Ideally, I want the colour to be White.

This image shows how it currently looks:

[image]

It looks like there is no 'Cancel' button, but there is, its just the same colour as the searchBar (You can still press it etc)

Is there a way for me to change the colour of this 'Cancel button to white? Everything i've tried seems to make no difference.

Code i've used to make the `UISearchBar` this colour is:

```
UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hue: 359/360, saturation: 67/100, brightness: 71/100, alpha: 1)
UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hue: 359/360, saturation: 67/100, brightness: 71/100, alpha: 1)
```

And in the storyboard i've set these:

[image]

And finally, to make the placeholder, and text white inside the SearchBar, i've used:

```
for subView in self.filmSearchBar.subviews {

    for subsubView in subView.subviews {

        if let searchBarTextField = subsubView as? UITextField {

            searchBarTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("Search Cinevu film reviews", comment: ""), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])

            searchBarTextField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: What color was the cancel button before?

Comment: @cbay It was the default colour which is like a light/faint gray

Comment: I haven't worked with search bars (and I do all my UI stuff programmatically), but where's the code for the cancel button? You should just be able to change the color with something like cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greyColor()

Comment: I was just looking at the docs. showsCancelButton defaults to NO. Try setting it to YES. I can't find where to change the color on it, if that's possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651374/how-to-change-cancel-button-tint-color-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838084/change-uibarbuttonitem-from-uisearchbar
might help you.

Comment: I have written an answer to this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206757/how-to-change-textcolor-of-cancel-button-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7. Just use the SHSearchBar Cocoapod which is not such a pain in the ass like the UISearchBar.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Having a look around, this seemed to be the best way to achieve what I needed:

```
 let cancelButtonAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes , for: .normal)
```

Comment: If you are using **UISearchController** you must insert this code to **willPresentSearchController:** or **didPresentSearchController:**

Comment: Does this affect anything else in the app or just the cancel button?

Comment: @ArthurGarza it only effects the cancel button

Comment: this affects the back button title color.

Answer (score 19):

Use this single line in code to change color of cancel button:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

Checked in Xcode 9.2 with Swift 4.0

Comment: Flawless victory.  Xcode 9.4.1, Swift 4.0, iOS 11.4.1

Comment: Just to simplify a bit:
... setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)

Answer (score 11):

Base on Nick89's code , I changed like that for Swift 3.1

```
let cancelButtonAttributes: [String: AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes, for: .normal)
```

I want to change on `UISearchBar` only instead of all UIBarButton, so I'm using like `UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])`

Comment: The same answer in **Swift 4**:  

    `let cancelButtonAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes, for: .normal)`

Answer (score 8):

did you try 
    UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

Comment: I have yes, It doesn't change the colour of the text. It just adds a faint outline to the button area.

Comment: you got a sample app you can upload?

Comment: @DavidYangLiu it also changes the cursor color?

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.2**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 6):

The Swift 4.2 version, based on other answers:

```
let cancelButtonAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.orange]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this question does have enough answers but here is simple way  to achieve, SearchBar Background colour and Cancel button background colour we can change directly  it in storyboard Attributes inspector.

for SearchBar background colour

[image]

for SearchBar cancel button colour

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the Swift 4.0 RELEASE 2017-09-19 toolchain, this worked:

```
    let cancelButtonAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set *tintcolor* of searchBar to change color of Cancel button. This is available since swift 4 so should do the trick.

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: )
searchBar.tintColor = .orange
```

[Search bar cancel button and cursor color change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXZ0C.png)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor : UIColor.barTint], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers didn't work for me. (Got 'Type 'NSAttributedString.Key' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'foregroundColor'' error)

Maybe because I'm at Swift 3...

Here's the slightly-modified code that worked for me:-

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : .black], for: .normal)
```

Note:-

If you are using UISearchController, insert this code to 'willPresentSearchController:' or 'didPresentSearchController:'

Answer (score -1):

`Swift` **4.2, 4.1**

A custom class added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345642) can be used to customize the most common elements in a searchBar. Custom class `SearchBar` can result in to the following search bar.

[image]