# UISearchbar add navigationController?.navigationBar,How to change "Cancel" color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

UISearchbar add navigationController?.navigationBar. How to change "Cancel" color

```
_searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 64)))
_searchBar!.delegate = self
_searchBar!.showsCancelButton = true
backgroundColor = .white
barTintColor = .white
tintColor = .red
backgroundImage = UIImage()
_searchBar!.placeholder = "搜索文件"
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(_searchBar!)
```

This result is "Cancel" color is white. How do I set it to red?

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302760/how-to-change-the-colour-of-the-cancel-button-on-the-uisearchbar-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `appearance` function of `UIAppearance` module -

**Method 1:-** Visible cancel button color when `searchBar` on load-

```
let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

or -

**Method 2:**- 
Visible cancel button color after `searchBar` clicked -

```
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: @ Jack Thank you very much, it is work ,but it must iOS9.0 , @Anbu.Karthink  answer applies to all system versions

Answer (score 0):

let ``` cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: ``UIColor.YOUR COLOR] ```
`UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as?` `[String : AnyObject], forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Comment: in the place Your color ADD UIColor.YOUR COLOR

Answer (score 0):

Changed the format to readability

```
let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.YOUR COLOR]     UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```